# Error updating npm

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble installing node.js and npm on my computer. I am running Windows 10 Pro x64, and using Windows Powershell (admin).

I downloaded node.js version: 9.10.1 from their website and ran the installation guide - clicking next on everything (I didn't change anything), then install.

I am trying to update npm from 5.6.0 to 5.8.0 and I am getting this error:

[image]

I checked the error log and it says:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'Z:\\Program\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'Z:\\Program\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'npm' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.10.1
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\Peter/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session c548a2e6f9e81d03
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData
8 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 267ms
9 silly pacote tag manifest for npm@latest fetched in 646ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
14 silly resolveWithNewModule npm@5.8.0 checking installable status
15 silly pacote trying https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.8.0.tgz by hash: sha512-DowXzQwtSWDtbAjuWecuEiismR0VdNEYaL3VxNTYTdW6AGkYxfGk9LUZ/rt6etEyiH4IEk95HkJeGfXE5Rz9xQ==
16 silly pacote data for sha512-DowXzQwtSWDtbAjuWecuEiismR0VdNEYaL3VxNTYTdW6AGkYxfGk9LUZ/rt6etEyiH4IEk95HkJeGfXE5Rz9xQ== not present. Using manifest.
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.8.0.tgz 15166ms
18 silly pacote https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.8.0.tgz extracted in 15380ms
19 silly addBundled read tarball
20 silly cleanup remove extracted module
21 silly saveTree Peter
21 silly saveTree `-- npm@5.8.0
21 silly saveTree   +-- abbrev@1.1.1
21 silly saveTree   +-- ansi-regex@3.0.0
21 silly saveTree   +-- ansicolors@0.3.2
21 silly saveTree   +-- ansistyles@0.1.3
21 silly saveTree   +-- aproba@1.2.0
21 silly saveTree   +-- archy@1.0.0
21 silly saveTree   +-- bin-links@1.1.0
21 silly saveTree   | +-- bluebird@3.5.1
21 silly saveTree   | +-- cmd-shim@2.0.2

//silly saveTree <<-- this goes on for a while, removed 95% of it..

21 silly saveTree   | +-- errno@0.1.7
21 silly saveTree   | | `-- prr@1.0.1
21 silly saveTree   | `-- xtend@4.0.1
21 silly saveTree   +-- wrappy@1.0.2
21 silly saveTree   `-- write-file-atomic@2.3.0
22 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'C:\Users\Peter\node_modules\npm\node_modules\JSONStream\npm-shrinkwrap.json'
23 verbose cwd C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Skola\Ionic_app
24 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
25 verbose argv "Z:\\Program\\nodejs\\node.exe" "Z:\\Program\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "npm"
26 verbose node v9.10.1
27 verbose npm  v5.6.0
28 error path C:\Users\Peter\node_modules\npm\node_modules\JSONStream\npm-shrinkwrap.json
29 error code ELOOP
30 error errno -4067
31 error syscall open
32 error ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'C:\Users\Peter\node_modules\npm\node_modules\JSONStream\npm-shrinkwrap.json'
33 verbose exit [ -4067, true ]
```

I have no idea what this all means.

How can I update npm to 5.8.0, and make sure that my installation is working properly?

Comment: Does this same error occur when you try to npm install some module or is it specific only to update?

Comment: I haven't tried installing any modules yet. I want to make sure that my node and npm installations are working properly first. (I've had problems with modules in the past, and I think that my node / npm installations might've been faulty back then.) I did a clean installation (I think) of node, and am now trying to make sure I have the latest version of everything, before I move onto installing modules.

Comment: You most likely want to do a global upgrade, with `npm i -g npm`. If it doesn't work, try appending `--no-bin-links` to the command.

Comment: @Svenskunganka thank you, using a global update seems to have done the trick!